# Entire local database sync with sql azure

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework, azure-data-sync

I am developing a windows application which is using local database.
I want to add a function to sync all local data to the sql azure.

Currently I used following code. It enabled me to sync one particular table successfully., here is "Author_Master"

```
 string sqlazureConnectionString = "XXXX";
 string sqllocalConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=Enh_Branchwise_Master_Bookshop;Trusted_Connection=True";

        using (SqlConnection serverCon = new SqlConnection(sqlazureConnectionString))
        using (SqlConnection clientCon = new SqlConnection(sqllocalConnectionString))
        {
            var provider1 = new SqlSyncProvider("scope1", serverCon);
            var provider2 = new SqlSyncProvider("scope1", clientCon);

            prepareServer(provider1);
            prepareClinet(provider2, serverCon);
            SyncOrchestrator sync = new SyncOrchestrator();
            sync.LocalProvider = provider1;
            sync.RemoteProvider = provider2;

            sync.Synchronize();

        }
```

And following methods also.

```
 private static void prepareServer(SqlSyncProvider provider)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)provider.Connection;
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning config = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(connection);

        if (!config.ScopeExists(provider.ScopeName))
        {
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(provider.ScopeName);
            scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Author_Master", connection));
            config.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
            config.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);
            config.Apply();
        }
    }

    private static void prepareClinet(SqlSyncProvider provider, SqlConnection sourceConnection)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)provider.Connection;
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning config = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(connection);

        if (!config.ScopeExists(provider.ScopeName))
        {
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(provider.ScopeName);
            scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Author_Master", sourceConnection));
            config.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
            config.Apply();
        }
    }
```

My question : Is there any way to sync all the tables in the database at once, without adding one by one table .

My both Databases have the same schema.
Please give some suggestions,

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Dear i am searching for the same how u have done this for one table can u please help me this thing for me

Comment: I have used following code to do that. You can try.

Comment: @las in m doing the same thing in mvc4 i have used your code but showing error in SqlSyncProvider and all

Comment: @las now i have remove all the code but now the problem is that it is not executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Dim clientProvision As SqlSyncScopeProvisioning = New SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientCon, syncScope)


                            If Not (clientProvision.ScopeExists("Scope_" + tableName)) Then
                                clientProvision.Apply()
                            End If

                            Dim serverProvision As SqlSyncScopeProvisioning = New SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverCon, syncScope)

                            If Not (serverProvision.ScopeExists("Scope_" + tableName)) Then
                                serverProvision.Apply()
                            End If

                            Dim syncOrchestrator As New SyncOrchestrator()

                            ' Create provider for SQL Server
                            Dim clientProvider As New SqlSyncProvider("Scope_" + tableName, clientCon)

                            ' Set the command timeout and maximum transaction size for the SQL Azure provider.
                            Dim serverProvider As New SqlSyncProvider("Scope_" + tableName, serverCon)

                            ' Set Local provider of SyncOrchestrator to the onPremise provider
                            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = clientProvider

                            ' Set Remote provider of SyncOrchestrator to the azureProvider provider 
                            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = serverProvider

                            ' Set the direction of SyncOrchestrator session to Upload and Download
                            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload


                            'Dim thread As New Threading.Thread(Sub() ShowStatistics(syncOrchestrator.Synchronize(), tableName))
                            'thread.Start()
                            ShowStatistics(syncOrchestrator.Synchronize(), tableName)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **SQL Data Sync** Tool.

SQL Data Sync is a feature of Windows Azure SQL Database.

With SQL Data Sync you can synchronize selected data through a Windows Azure SQL Database instance.

SQL Data Sync supports synchronizations within or across Windows Azure data centers.

SQL Data Sync also supports hybrid configurations of SQL Database instances and on-premises SQL Server databases.

The SQL Data Sync service is free.

For more details check [**ScottGu's Blog Post**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/21/great-updates-to-windows-azure-mobile-services-web-sites-sql-data-sync-acs-media-more.aspx) under "SQL Data Sync" sub topic.

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: @JuneT thanks for valuable information.I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: @las check this tool.May be help to you.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Sync Framework, you have to tell it explicitly which tables (or even columns) to actually sync.

Comment: Currently I am using it, is it ok to iterate all the tables from the database query and execute above code

Comment: you only need to provision once. yes, you can iterate thru a list of tables in add them to a scope.

Comment: ok, thank you for suggestion, that is the thing I'm going to use now

Answer (score -1):

You can use **SQL Database Migration Wizard** (SQLAzureMW) for that.

It is an open source application.

You can use it to migrate your SQL database to and from Windows Azure SQL Database.

SQLAzureMW has a user interactive wizard that walks a person through the analysis / migration process.

For get more details about [**SQL Database Migration Wizard**](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: @las why's that?Is there any special requirement or something like that ?

Comment: the migration wizard is not a synchronization tool. its a migration tool. you can't do incremental synchronization with a migration tool.